# Understanding the construction of the Euler class

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-forms, vector-bundles

I am following Bott & Tu, *Differential forms in Algebraic Topology*, section 6 about Euler class and Thom class. However, I am stucked at a technical detail. To be more specific, let $\pi: E \to M$ be an oriented vector bundle of rank $2$ of smooth manifolds and $E^0$ the complement of the zero section. Fixing a Riemannian structure on $E$ and choose an oriented trivializations $(U_{\alpha})$. The authors observe:

> ... over each $U_{\alpha}$ we can choose an orthogonal frame. This defines on $\pi^{-1}(U_{\alpha})=E_{\mid U_{\alpha}}$ polar coordinates $r_{\alpha},\theta_{\alpha}$; if $x_1,...,x_n$ are coordinates on $U_{\alpha}$, then $\pi^* x_1,...,\pi^* x_n, r_{\alpha},\theta_{\alpha}$ are coordinates on $E^0_{\mid U_{\alpha}}$. On $U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}$ the angular $\theta_{\alpha},\theta_{\beta}$ differ by a rotation so due to the orientability of $E$ we can write $\theta_{\beta}=\theta_{\alpha}+\pi^*\phi_{\alpha \beta} (0 \leq \phi_{\alpha \beta} < 2\pi)$.

My intuition, at least in some trivial cases, I could figure out what the authors mean here but can not write down everything explicitly. Could someone help me to write the formulas of $r_{\alpha},\theta_{\alpha},\phi_{\alpha \beta}$ and explain why $\pi^* x_1,...,\pi^* x_n, r_{\alpha},\theta_{\alpha}$ are coordinates on $E^0_{\mid U_{\alpha}}$?

If the $\phi_{\alpha \beta}$'s are well-defined then there exists $1$-forms $\zeta_{\alpha}$ on $U_{\alpha}$ such that $d\phi_{\alpha \beta} = 2\pi(\zeta_{\alpha}-\zeta_{\beta})$ and hence the $\zeta_{\alpha}$'s can be glued to a $2$-form on $M$, denote $e \in H^2(M)$ which is called the Euler class of this vector bundle.

Comment: Choose a local trivialisation over $U_a$. Then $E|_{U_a}\cong U_a\times R^2$. Local coordinates on the product are of the form (coordinates on M)x(coordinates on $R^2$). Thus the claimed (n+2)-tuple are coordinates on $E|_{U_a}^0\cong U_a\times (R^2\setminus0)$. The $r_a$ and $\theta_a$ are the standard polar coordiantes on $R^2\setminus0$ (composed with your local trivialisation). You can find expressions for these on wiki.